# Animated SVG - Gif fallback for IE / Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, microsoft-edge

I am using an animated SVG which works great in all browsers I have tried apart from IE / Edge.

```
<img src="img/loaderk.svg" alt="Loading">
```

Is there any sort of fallback I can do to display an animated gif instead if IE or Edge is detected?

Or do I need to to this with Javascript instead?

Comment: i guess the easiest way would to check for browser support using modernizr and alter the markup using js, yes